# Migrate multiple databases with Propel

Tags: php, mysql, database-migration, propel

I am maintaining a system with many databases. One “central" db, and many other “client” dbs. Each time a client registers, we create a client db using an SQL file. The system is using Propel + PHP + MySQL.

Now the problem is, there are changes when we do version-up. It’s possible to use Propel migration for central db, but there are MANY client dbs, and in propel.yaml/ propel-config.php we only have ONE connection string for client like this:

```
$manager = new \Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionManagerSingle();
$manager->setConfiguration(array(
    'classname' => 'Propel\\Runtime\\Connection\\ConnectionWrapper',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=' . $shopDbName . ';charset=UTF8',
    'user' => 'dba',
    'password' => ‘******',
    'attributes' =>
        array(
            'ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES' => false,
        ),
));
```

in which $shopDbName is the global variable identified by a string sent from client devices.

So, how can I automate the process of migration for client dbs in this case, please?

Comment: You can create multiple connections in your propel.yaml file, and then specify a default connection for generator, one for migration, and one for runtime.  This is also dependent on how your databases are distributed.  Can you elaborate how are sharing the migrstion file for each client?